# Unable to create Java Library Binding with native .SO

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, binding

I am creating a Java Library Binding project. The purpose is to create a simple application for RFID scanning, deployed on a Android-based RFID handheld scanner.
I have native libraries. There is one.JAR and a few.SO files.
I have created a Xamarin Java Binding project in VS2017 and put the .JAR in "Jars" folder. I have set the Build Action to EmbeddedJar.
I have created a separate folder for native libs and in there put the .SO file with Build Action EmbeddedNativeLibrary.
I get the following error on build:

> The "CreateNativeLibraryArchive" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\src\RfidSDK\RfidSDK\obj\Debug__AndroidNativeLibraries__.zip.new'.
>   File name: 'C:\src\RfidSDK\RfidSDK\obj\Debug__AndroidNativeLibraries__.zip.new'
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.CopyIfZipChanged(String source, String destination)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.ArchiveZip(String target, Action`1 archiver)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.CreateNativeLibraryArchive.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

I am not sure what the issue is...

Many Thanks for any help,

Tried switching the Target framework, no difference.

Comment: I also get the following warning in VS2017:
Native library 'NativeLibs\libDeviceAPI.so' will not be bundled because it has an unsupported ABI.

Comment: Tried VS2019? It is actually up to date with the Xamarin.Android bits...

Comment: Tried VS2019, same issue. However I did manage to solve it. The issue is it uses "path sniffing" to determine the ABI version. I simply created a new folder called arm64-v8a and put the .SO files in this and then the project compiled. (Or rather moved on to unrelated other issues. ^^)

Comment: Thanks @RoleyBaxter I added an image to your solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

Following the solution in @RoleyBaxter's comment:

[image]